# Mono for Android: Reverse GeoCoding Current Location

Tags: android, mono, geolocation, xamarin.android, mapactivity

Using the `MyLocationOverlay` I get the current GeoPoint of the user.

```
        myLocationOverlay.RunOnFirstFix (() => {
            mapView.Controller.AnimateTo (myLocationOverlay.MyLocation);
            RunOnUiThread (() => {
                DisplayIncidentsNearMe (myLocationOverlay.MyLocation);}
            );
        }
        );
```

However, To ReverseGeoCode that location, I need the Lat/Lng. The GeoPoint from the MyLocationOverlay is in LatitudeE6 format so doesn't work.

How do I get the "normal" lat/lng from the location object returned from the `MyLocationOverlay`?

```
        Geocoder geo = new Geocoder (this, Java.Util.Locale.Default);
        var ad = geo.GetFromLocation (myLocation.LatitudeE6, myLocation.LongitudeE6, 1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [GeoPoint documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/GeoPoint#getLatitudeE6%28%29), LatitudeE6 is:

> the latitude of this GeoPoint in microdegrees (degrees * 1E6).

You can convert this number back to degrees by dividing by 1e6:

```
double degrees = myLocation.LatitudeE6 / 1e6;
```